# DRM options in Ebook reader app

Tags: android, ios, epub, drm

One of my client wants to develop an app which allows publisher to sell the eBooks.

Do anyone have any idea or experience of any DRM provider?

I did able to find following options for applying DRM:

[Sony URMS](https://www.datalogics.com/products/edtechandebook/sonydadcurms/) - It's looks bit extensive and it is designed to work with old versions readium rendering engine. Moreover I am not sure about the support they will provide if we got stuck while development. I asked few questions to them, but yet to get any answer from them.

[Sky Epub](https://skyepub.net/) - Sky Epub looks good. But client is hesitant to use that since no big name behind that brand.

[Readium LCP](https://github.com/readium/readium-lcp-server) - It looks good, but it is open source. So we have to install, setup, configure and later maintain everything which will increase development cost. Initially, client would like to go with SaaS DRM provider.

Anyone have any idea about SkyEpub? Or any alternative DRM solution except Adobe?

Answer (score 0):

Sony URMS support is discontinued and SkyEpub is from what I know a SDK, not a DRM technology (and certainly not interoperable if they provide an ebook protection).

Readium LCP is a (non-proprietary) distributed solution, so yes license providers have to install and maintain a server. But some Saas LCP provider are coming. Contact EDRLab if you want to keep in touch on this subject.